# Webpack compile time changes for no reason

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project and am using webpack through Laravel mix.  I understand that there can be problems running with webpack `watch` mode when running in a VM, and so I am running with the `watch-poll` flag.

This is still not working as expected - for example, the poll doesn't seem to work, however when I click on the terminal session where webpack is running, it jumps to life.  I can live with that, but the big problem is that sometimes the compile time jumps to 10X what it normally is.

Typically, when I first run `npm run watch-poll` it takes about 25 seconds.  The next few iterations take, say, 8 seconds, which is great.  Then suddenly it will start to take 80 seconds, sometimes longer.  What could possibly lead to this?  Each time I am making the same tiny change to the same CSS rule (changing the background colour of a div).

I have started with a new Laravel Homestead machine, and upgraded my application to Laravel 5.6, but it has not made any difference.

When I run webpack with the `--profile` option, I see that it is spending almost all of its time in 'building modules'.

EDIT: The problem exists even on a new Laravel project.  The times jump around from about 5 seconds, to 15 seconds.

Comment: What is your `laravel-mix` version?

Comment: Laravel mix version 1.7.2

Comment: Try installing `2.0.0` and see if it helps. It has breaking changes.

Comment: Just upgraded to 2.0.0 but problem still remains...

Comment: Could the problem be somewhere along `process urls`?